# Get assignees and assigner via PyGithub

Tags: github-api, pygithub

I'm using PyGithub to interact with GitHub API and trying to get assignees and assigner on issues. I implemented the following code, and it seem that assignee name and assigner name are not correct. For instance, `clatoolkitdev2` was assigned by `clatoolkitdev` on [issue #32](https://api.github.com/repos/clatoolkitdev/GitHubIntegrationTest/issues/32/events). However, I got `clatoolkitdev2` as assignee and assigner from my code.

```
gh = Github(login_or_token = token, per_page = self.parPage)
repo = gh.get_repo(repo_name)
issue = repo.get_issue(issue_number)
issue_events = issue.get_events().get_page(page)

for event in issue_events:
    assignee = event.issue.assignee
    assigner = event.actor

    assigner_id = str(assigner.id)
    assigner_name = str(assigner.login)
    assignee_name = assignee.login

    print '================================================================='
    print 'event ID: ' + str(event_id) + "     " + issue_url
    print 'assigner: %s  assignee: %s' % (assigner_name, assignee_name)
```

The output:

```
=================================================================
event ID: 866189924     https://github.com/clatoolkitdev/GitHubIntegrationTest/issues/32
assigner: clatoolkitdev2  assignee: clatoolkitdev2
=================================================================
event ID: 803384175     https://github.com/clatoolkitdev/GitHubIntegrationTest/issues/25
assigner: kojiclatoolkit  assignee: kojiclatoolkit
=================================================================
event ID: 803384176     https://github.com/clatoolkitdev/GitHubIntegrationTest/issues/25
assigner: clatoolkitdev  assignee: kojiclatoolkit
=================================================================
event ID: 852475091     https://github.com/clatoolkitdev/GitHubIntegrationTest/issues/24
assigner: kojiclatoolkit  assignee: kojiclatoolkit
=================================================================
event ID: 852475092     https://github.com/clatoolkitdev/GitHubIntegrationTest/issues/24
assigner: clatoolkitdev  assignee: kojiclatoolkit
```

I checked PyGithub API reference and googled to find a solution but didn't get any clue. I was wondering whether I made stupid mistakes or there is a bug in PyGithub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that PyGithub (and your code) is reading the `actor.login` property of the event to get the assigner, which is in fact `clatoolkitdev2` in the API response you provided.

Looking at the PyGithub source, it doesn't seem to ever read the `assigner` property from the API payload (neither in [`Issue.py`](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/master/github/Issue.py) nor [`IssueEvent.py`](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/master/github/IssueEvent.py)), which strikes me as a bug.

Comment: Hmm, looks like it. I didn't know what to do, so I access the GitHub API directly without using PyGithub to get assignees and assigner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer